# Find the types of discontinuity points

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $, $f(x) =\left\{\begin{matrix}
1, x\in \mathbb{Q} & \\ 
x^2+2, x\in \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q} & 
\end{matrix}\right.$. What are the types of its discontinuity points?
My work : I know that the only continuity points are the real solutions of the equation $x^2+2=1$. As this equation has no real solutions, the function is discontinuous at any point. However, I don't know how to find their types.

Answer (score 1):

There's two types of discontinuities at a point $x_0$, either $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0, x\neq x_0} f(x)$ does not exist, either $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0, x\neq x_0} f(x)$ does exist but is not equal to $f(x)$. Here, the problem is that the limit does not exist.

Indeed, let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, take a sequence $(y_n)$ of rational numbers such that $y_n\to x$ and $(z_n)$ of rational numbers such that $z_n\to x$. Then $f(x_n)\to 1$ and $f(z_n)\to 2 + x^2\neq 1$. Therefore, $f$ cannot have a limit at the point $x$.